# My colors.xml file not showing the theme color. everything is in grey color. how to solve this?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

[image]

After downloading android studio 4.0 canary my colors.xml file are not showing any theme color. I can able to access all the colors but my other variable in kotlin file and color.xml are in gray color.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

colors are resource directory so it must be wrapped by resource tag

Like this :

< resources>

(Your colors here)

< /resources>

Remove the space after '<'